# I want to create a custom list as shown in screenshot and I am using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image: The List Which I want to make.]

My main CSS code is:

```
.bg-blue {
   background-color: #022E3D;
   color: white;
}

.bg-blue ul li {
   background-image: url(http://s32.postimg.org/fdofyahrp/Icon.png);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   padding-left: 5em;
   background-size: auto;
   padding-bottom: 3em;
}
.bg-blue ul li::before {
   content: " ";
   min-height: 59px;
   display: block;
   background-color: #d5d5d5;
   width: 1px;
   position: relative;
   top: 3.5em;
   left: -50px;
}

.bg-blue ul li:last-child:before {
    content: " ";
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Here is the Fiddle :https://jsfiddle.net/amanturate/sznqax6b/7/

The main problem is that text is not being aligned next to the image. Is there a better way to do it? I am using Bootstrap v3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `:after` pseudo-element instead of `:before` and adjust top position of the pseudo-elements':

```
.bg-blue ul li::after {
  content: " ";
  min-height: 59px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #d5d5d5;
  width: 1px;
  position: relative;
  top: 2em;
  left: -50px;
}

.bg-blue ul li:last-child:after {
  content: " ";
  background-color: transparent;
}
```